# how to explore a branch's history?

Tags: git

I'd like to know the exact changes made to a branch that were made by a developer.

Considering this branch was merged into master a several times, Is there a way to tell the very changes that were made by the developer throughout history?

I'd like to add, is there a way to see the changes made excluding merges, so I can focus on the developers work exclusively?

Comment: which git are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Greg Hewgill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54275242/1256452), which is to use the `--author` selector to select specific commits.  You might want to add `--no-merges` as well.  That's going to select *only those commits made by that particular author-name*—and with `--no-merges`, exclude merge commits too, even if they are also by that author—which is not quite the same as what you asked for, but *may* be all you can realistically get, depending on how much care people took with the repository.

But you may be able to do quite a lot better, using `git log --first-parent`.  That depends, again, on how much care people took when making commits in the repository.

The first thing to do here is to let go of the notion that a branch is defined by its name, because in a very important way, it's not!

In Git, the commits *are* the history.  Each commit is identified by a big ugly hash ID such as `0d0ac3826a3bbb9247e39e12623bbcfdd722f24c` (this is an actual commit in the Git repository for Git itself).  Git uses this ID to locate the internal data structures that make up the frozen snapshot and the metadata (the author name, log message, and so on) for that commit.  In the metadata, Git stores the hash ID of the commit's *parent* commit—the commit that was the active commit when you, or whoever made the commit, made it.  So, by starting at one commit, with, say, hash `H`—this stands in for the big ugly hash ID—and working backwards, Git can go from `H` to its parent `G`, and then back again from `G` to *its* parent `F`, and so on:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

A branch name like `master` or `develop` serves only to identify *one specific commit*, which Git calls the *tip* of the branch:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

In other words, the branch name holds the actual hash ID of the *last* commit you want to call "part of the branch".  That lets Git start at the end, and work backwards.

Obviously, if you add a *new* commit to the end, this "last commit" pointer has to *move*, and that's precisely what it means to add a commit to a branch.  Git will package up the source snapshot, add your name and email address and the time, add your log message, save the hash ID of the *current* (branch-tip) commit, and write out the new commit:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I
```

Writing out the commit produces the new commit's hash ID, so now Git has a unique big ugly string of letters and digits that lets it find commit `I`.

As its final act, `git commit` now writes the hash ID of new commit `I` into the name `master`, and now you have:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master
```

Once you make any commit, everything *about* that commit is frozen forever, including its backwards-pointing internal arrow: `I` permanently points back to `H`.  (Nothing can ever change this: at most, you can make a new-and-improved `I2` or `I'` that *also* points back to `H`, and switch your `master` to point to the new and improved variant.  As long as you do this before anyone else starts using `I`, that's quite safe, and that's what `git commit --amend` does, for instance.  But this also means we don't need to draw the internal arrows as arrows, we just need to remember that they only let Git go backwards.)

Now, there's something special about a *merge* commit.  Let's take a repository with just three commits:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

Now let's make a new branch, `develop`.  To do that, Git just adds a new *name*, pointing to some *existing* commit.  Typically that's the one we have out now, i.e., commit `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, develop
```

Now we have an obvious problem: how shall we know which commit to *update* when we make a new one?  The answer is that we attach the special name `HEAD` to one of these two branches:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, develop (HEAD)
```

This tells Git (and us) that we're on `develop` rather than `master`.  We're still using commit `C` either way, but now when we make a new commit `D` it will move only the name `develop`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

The name `HEAD` remains attached to the branch, even as the branch itself moves.

We can now add a few more commits to `develop`, and maybe—or maybe not—`git checkout master` (going back to commit `C`) and add a few commits there too.  Let's do both:

```
A--B--C--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
       \
        D--E--F   <-- develop
```

Now let's run `git merge develop`.  The goal of this merge is to *combine work:* to take what we did on `master`—whatever is different from `C` to `H`–with whatever "they" (really, "we") did on `develop`, i.e., whatever is different from `C` to `F`.  Without worrying too much about *how* Git combines these two sets of changes, it's pretty clear that this is the way to go: we started with `C` and change it to get to `H`, and they started with `C` and changed it to get to `F`, so whatever we changed, and whatever they changed, is whatever is different from this common starting point.

(The common starting point is called the *merge base*, and it's crucial for understanding *how* merge works.  We're skipping over the *how* for now, but you should definitely remember the idea behind finding merge bases.  If you draw a simple graph like this, the commit to use for the merge base is obvious.  In real repositories, the graphs get complicated and it's often not so easy to see—but Git will find it for you.)

Anyway, assuming the merge works properly, Git ends up making a new commit on its own, with the merged code as the new commit's snapshot.  This merge commit has not one but *two* parents:

```
A--B--C--G--H---I   <-- master (HEAD)
       \       /
        D--E--F   <-- develop
```

Importantly (and not something I can draw), the *first* parent of new merge commit `I` is the commit we were on before, i.e., commit `H`.  The *second* parent of new merge commit `I` is the commit we told Git to merge, i.e., commit `F`.

Suppose whoever is developing `develop` now goes on to make more commits in `develop`, while we sit still here at `I` on `master`:

```
A--B--C--G--H---I   <-- master (HEAD)
       \       /
        D--E--F--J--K--L   <-- develop
```

We can now merge again, using `git merge develop`.  This time, the fact that `I` goes back to both `H` *and* `F` means that the common starting point is commit `F`, so we're just going to pick up the *new* work they've done:

```
A--B--C--G--H---I--------M   <-- master (HEAD)
       \       /        /
        D--E--F--J--K--L   <-- develop
```

This pattern will repeat, no matter how much work they—whoever they are—do on `develop`, as long as we make sure that our merges work like this.  We did our merges with just `git merge`, without any special care taken, but we started with our own work on `master` in commits `G--H`, and *they* never did `git merge master` into *their* `develop`.

Suppose, though, that at this point whoever is working on `develop` does:

```
git checkout develop
git merge master
```

You might expect this to make a new merge commit on `develop`, but it won't!  Instead, Git will notice that `develop`—i.e., commit `L`—is right behind commit `M`, the merge commit on `master`.

Git will therefore do what it calls a *fast-forward merge*, which is not a merge at all.  It's really just a `git checkout` that drags the branch name forward.  In this case, it makes both `develop` and `master` point to commit `M`:

```
A--B--C--G--H---I--------M   <-- master, develop (HEAD)
       \       /        /
        D--E--F--J--K--L
```

If whoever is working on `develop` *now* makes some new commits, they go like this, with the first one pointing to `M` as its (first and only) parent:

```
A--B--C--G--H---I--------M   <-- master
       \       /        / \
        D--E--F--J--K--L   N--O   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Had whoever was working on `develop` used special care, they would have run `git merge --no-ff master` instead of just `git merge master`, which would have done this:

```
A--B--C--G--H---I--------M   <-- master
       \       /        / \
        D--E--F--J--K--L---N   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Here, `N` is a two-parent *merge* commit, with its *first* parent being `L`, and its second parent being merge `M` on `master`.  Then new commits on `develop` would continue in the pattern we'd like:

```
A--B--C--G--H---I--------M   <-- master
       \       /        / \
        D--E--F--J--K--L---N--O--P   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Note that it's now crucial that whoever manages `master` *also* use `git merge --no-ff` to merge commit `P` back into `master`.  A `--no-ff` true-merge commit will result in:

```
A--B--C--G--H---I--------M---------Q   <-- master (HEAD)
       \       /        / \       /
        D--E--F--J--K--L---N--O--P   <-- develop
```

with the *first* parent of `Q` being `M`, and the *second* parent being `P`.  Without `--no-ff`, Git would simply *check out* `P` and make both branch names point to commit `P`, rather than making a real merge that maintains the desired "first parent" property.

Anyway, *if* whoever made merges in the repository used proper care to make sure that this first-parent property is obeyed, you can simply find the *last* commit that was ever made on `develop` and use `git log --first-parent`, perhaps also with `--no-merges` to skip over the merge commits.

Note that what all these `git log` commands share is that they only show you *some* commits.  The `--author` flag tells `git log`: *Show me commits whose author matches what I say.*  The `--no-merges` flag tells `git log`: *Don't show merge commits at all.*  (The default is to show them, but even with `-p`, not to show any diff.)  Git still *looks at* all the commits it can, by working backwards and, at merge commits, looking at *all* their parents.  (It still just *shows* one commit at a time, and that's a little bit tricky as well, when it has two or more commits it "wants" to show at the same time.)

The `--first-parent` flag is a little different.  It tells `git log`: *Follow only the first-parent link whenever you step backwards through a merge.*  That is, if we have Git start at commit `P` and work backwards, it will show `P`, then show `O`.  Since `N` is a merge commit, Git won't *show* it if we use `--no-merges`, but it would step back to *both* `M` *and* `L` now.  From `M`, Git would step back to *both* `L` *and* `I`.  If we add `--first-parent`, though, Git *won't* take both parents.  Instead, it will add only the *first* parent of `N` to the list of commits to show.  So it will step from `N` to `L`—the first parent, following the original `develop` only.  It will then show `L`, and step back to `K`, and `J`, and `F`, and so on.

(Git will eventually step right back to `C` and we'll need to know to stop looking at this point, but that's going to happen no matter how we choose to look at these commits.  Using `--author` might make Git not show `C`, provided it has a different author, but we'll still see `B` and/or `A` too if those have the selected author.)

Note that this technique works *even if the name `develop` has been deleted.*  We just have to find the *last* commit we want Git to start from, and use `--first-parent` to make `git log` walk backwards from there, following the first-parent links.  But it depends on whoever did the merges having done them the way we'd like.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get a list of changes made by a particular developer is to use `git log --author`, for example:

```
git log --author=fred@example.com
```

If you use a GUI tool like `gitk` or similar, they all have options to search for commits by author name/email.